# More efficient way to write if-conditionals with repetitive variable

Tags: c, performance, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm looking for a more efficient way to write these kinds of if-conditionals:

```
a = huge_term >= b ? huge_term : c
```

or

```
(a = huge_term) >= b ? a : a = c
```

The second one is quite shorter but the variable `a` appears 3 times.
I need the result to be stored in a variable.
How would you write it?

Comment: The first way as that's "how I've always done it."  Hmm, you've got me thinking now...

Comment: Is `a` a volatile machine register? Why are you concerned about a being repeated?

Comment: At some point the tradeoff between "efficiency" and readability becomes a net loss

Comment: Would the second method be "shorter" if the variable were called "my_huge_term_holder"?

Comment: Probably not because a term which is lexically as long as the name "my_huge_term_holder" cannot legitimately be called huge.

Comment: Shorter != better (not always anyway).

Comment: It needs to be benchmarked. As @Kaz said, if CSE kicks in, `huge_term` does not matter, it will be computed only once. Then as number of comparison is same, only how many times data is getting loaded to accumulator counts. In my opinion, first should be faster

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, are you sure it should be C and not C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using intermediate variables and breaking up the logic into its own function. Generally, whenever I find conditional logic like this, it shows up again and again in my project, so refactoring it saves time in the long run.

```
Type processInput(const Type input)
{
  auto result = input;
  if ( input < b )
  {
    result = c;
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  const auto input = huge_term;
  const auto result = processInput(input);
}
```

Comment: +1 - the more intermediate local vars the better.  When debugging, you can do an 'optimization off' build and the 'extra' vars make debugging a pile easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is ok but additional complication of the expression will make it unreadable and it would probably be better to use `if` instead.

The second "method" is both unreadable and inefficient - redundant computations are present. Don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely it's better to have a variable appear several times than a big expression.

It might not make an efficiency difference either way, but from an program organization point of view, it's better not to repeat large blocks of code.

If `huge_term` is something that a compiler can recognize as a common subexpression whose value doesn't change between the two evaluations, it can be eliminated via CSE (common subexpression elimination). But just because the compiler can reduce it doesn't mean it isn't a maintenance headache.

How many times a variable appears is hardly anything to be concerned about, especially if it helps to reduce repetition of a large exprssion. That is, unless the variable is a volatile memory location like an I/O port.  If assigment to `a` is an externally visible effect, then the two versions do not have the same semantics.